# React Native change Image based on index

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I got cards on top of eachother rendered with some images and i want to cycle through my image array using an index.
The console shows me that my cycle works as intended but the image is not getting updated :/
ps: I am using https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper

[SwipeCard.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQXpV.png)

```
renderCard={(card) => {
                let ImageIndex = 0;
                const ImageCycle = () => {
                    ImageIndex === card.Image.length - 1 ? ImageIndex = 0 : ImageIndex++
                    console.log(ImageIndex);
                    return ImageIndex
                    
                }
                return (
                    <View style={styles.card} key={card.id}>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {ImageCycle()}}>
                            <Image style={styles.image} source={card.Image[ImageIndex]}/>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

[Cards.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X2FN.png)

```
Image:   [
        require('../ProfileImages/Sydney.jpg'),
        require('../ProfileImages/Sydney.jpg'),
        require('../ProfileImages/Sydney.jpg'),
],
```

I thought about using useState but I'm not quite sure how to use it here

Comment: You should add code as text here, not the image

Answer (score 0):

Oh! It seems like the issue you're facing is related to the way the Image component and the ImageCycle function interact. In your code, you are calling the ImageCycle function when the TouchableWithoutFeedback is pressed. However, the function doesn't seem to directly update the Image component. To achieve the desired behavior of cycling through the images, you can manage the image index in the component's state and update it using the setState function.

Here's an example that might be helpful for you:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// ...

function YourComponent() {
  const [ImageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);

  const ImageCycle = () => {
    const newIndex = (ImageIndex + 1) % card.Image.length;
    setImageIndex(newIndex);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.card} key={card.id}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ImageCycle}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={card.Image[ImageIndex]} />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      {/* Add other card content here */}
    </View>
  );
}

// ...

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks for it but sadly i get a render error for an Invalid hook call probably because i need to call the state inside the renderCard function to get the card.Image :/

Comment: Oh you can let me know in case you need any further help on this. Maybe if you can create a sandbox for your code, I can solve it very quickly. 